# Suppose a and b are real numbers. Prove that if $a < b < 0$ then $a^2 > b^2$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

I'm reading the book "How to prove it" and this is one of the exercises. I'm trying to prove this statement and I was wondering if this counts as a proof.

Suppose a and b are real numbers. Prove that if $a < b < 0$ then $a^2 > b^2$

To start off we have:

$$(a < b < 0) \rightarrow (a^2 > b^2)\tag 1$$

We look at the contrapositive of this statement:

$$\lnot (a^2 > b^2) \rightarrow \lnot (a < b < 0)\tag 2$$

We look at the left side and write it as:

$$b^2 \leq a^2\tag 3$$

$$\frac{b^2}{a} \leq a\tag 4$$

The only way this can be true is if:

$$b^2 \leq a = b \leq \frac{a}{b}\tag 5$$

Which means

$$a \geq b\tag 6$$

Which means $b \not\gt a$

Therefore
$$\lnot (a^2 > b^2) \rightarrow \lnot (a < b < 0)\tag 7$$ is true and we can conclude that

$$(a < b < 0) \rightarrow (a^2 > b^2)\tag 8$$

Does this count as a correct proof? If not can you point out my mistakes and how I possibly could have solved it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The implication $b^2 \le a^2 \implies \frac{b^2}{a} \le a$ is only true if $a > 0$. Since you don't know that (that's part of what you are trying to prove), the proof is invalid. There may be more invalid steps later: that's the first place where you go off the rails.

Comment: the step from $(3)$ to $(4)$ only works for $a>0$. The meaning of $(5)$ is completely unclear to me, so I do not know how  $(6)$ follows from $(5)$

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I would just say that if $a < b < 0$, then we know that $|a| > |b|$, and thus $a^2 = (-|a|)^2 = |a|^2 > |b|^2 = (-|b|)^2 = b^2$ where the inequality stems from the monotonicity of the square function.

Comment: I thought about doing this, but the book almost always shows a "harder" way. Is the proof I made incorrect though?

Comment: I don't know if my approach is harder, since you're implicitly making similar things when you rewrite $\neg (a^2 > b^2)$ to $b^2 \leq a^2$.
Furthermore, when you divide through one $a$, the comparison operator changes again, since $a < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The step after you say "we look at the left side and write it as "...""  Is wrong. It should have been: $\lnot( a^2 \gt b^2)\equiv a^2\leq b^2$. Therefore, the proof is wrong.

Let me explain why that is wrong: $a \gt b$ means $(a\gt b)\land (a\neq b)$; therefore, when you negate it the conjunction becomes: $(a\lt b) \lor (a=b)$. Which is nothing but the implication of demorgan's law.

Instead of a direct proof I suggest you do an indirect proof:

Show: $P \implies Q$, by supposing $\lnot (P\implies Q)\equiv P \land \lnot Q$ and showing a contradiction:

Suppose: $(a\lt b\lt 0) \land a^2\leq b^2$

By quaring the first conjunct we get, $a^2\gt b^2\gt 0$, but we assumed in the second conjunct that $a^2\leq b^2$. Since both conjuncts are mutually contradictory. Our assumption that $\lnot (P\implies Q)$ is false, and therefore $P \implies Q$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

> We look at the contrapositive of this statement:
>
> $$\lnot (a^2 > b^2) \rightarrow \lnot (a < b < 0)\tag 2$$
>
> We look at the left side and write it as:
>
> $$b^2 \leq a^2\tag 3$$

It's hard for me to work out what you're trying to do with this proof, but you seem to be trying to write $\lnot (a^2>b^2)$ here, if so this should say

$$b^2 \geq a^2\tag 3$$

You can either put the $a^2$ after the $b^2$ or you can put the inequality the other way around, but if you do both at the same time the two things cancel each other out. The only reason I can guess that you're trying to write the contrapositive is because you have $\leq$ rather than $<$ in your equation.

> $$b^2 \leq a^2\tag 3$$
>
> $$\frac{b^2}{a} \leq a\tag 4$$

Since we are given $a<0$, then when you divide by $a$ the inequality is reversed, so that should read

$$\frac{b^2}{a} \geq a\tag 4$$

> The only way this can be true is if:
>
> $$b^2 \leq a = b \leq \frac{a}{b}\tag 5$$

It is clear that $b^2>0>a$ so the first part is not true, then you have divided by a negative number again. Also the equals sign seems to be a substitute for $\implies$ (`\implies`) here.

> Does this count as a correct proof? If not can you point out my mistakes and how I possibly could have solved it?

No it's not a correct proof at all. You might be able to rescue it if you can sort out all of the problems with division by negatives and putting the inequalities the wrong way around.

But you can prove this result by noting that $(a+b)(a-b)=\text{negative}\times\text{negative}=\text{positive}$ and $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$.

Answer (score -1):

A different and very basic proof is the following:

It holds that $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)>0$ since $a-b,a+b<0$.

Comment: the question was if the OP's proof is correct. The op didn't ask for a different proof

Comment: I'm perfectly aware, and I figured that the OP did get an answer since the question is 3 years old. At some point someone could be looking for a way to prove that $a<b<0$ implies $a^2>b^2$ and come across this question. In my mind this is the simplest proof of this fact so I wanted it to be available.

Comment: @miracle173 this answer is not wrong. Plus its best to find the easiest solution to the problem, as OP's methods need not make sense after step 4 and 5...

Comment: @UnexpectedConfusion This answer is not an answer to this question. I am pretty sure that if the OP had asked 'Prove that if a<b<0 then a2>b2' then this questions would be closed as duplicate and these is variant of the question answer like this one. but actually I don't really care.

Comment: @miracle173 isn't the question about proving a²  >  b² given that a < b < 0  ?